# How to Check if a File is Encrypted or not?

Tags: apex, api, integration, upload

I have a requirement to check whether a file is encrypted (using AES) or not before uploading. If not encrypted the upload should not happen and an Error Message should be thrown. How in APEX/Java Script this be achieved? What patterns should I watch for in the File?

Answer (score 1):

By the time the file gets to the server in order to be checked to see if its encrypted it has already been transmitted over the network.  Which makes checking to see if its been encrypted for 'secure' transport pointless.

The appropriate solution in this case is procedural controls at the user end.

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to find whether your file has been encrypted by AES unless you decrypt. What i suggest is adding your custom header before AES encryption and then decrypt the file and look for the header again in decrypted file .

Comment: Answer looks wordy from me but certainly i will work on improving this with code :).But hope that the basic logic is interesting !